# Error: No similarly named formulae found. Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, terminal

So, I'm using macOS Big Sur. So I typed:

python --version

Python 2.7.16

brew install python

I got this error message when I want to update my python via my terminal.

```
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python".
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.
```

I would like to update it to Python 3, so when I run my commands on VSC. I can just type python instead of python3. What does this error message mean?

Comment: Your system might still be relying on processes that use python2. If you want multiple python installs, a virtual environment manager is well-suited to this task. It's best not to modify your system-installed python

Comment: @francescowang -Have you tried to download and install Python3 from the [Python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/)?

Answer (score 51):

Run this command in terminal:

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core)
```

Then try:

```
 brew install python3
```

it will install python 3.9.

Comment: This works for install anything when facing this error.

Answer (score -2):

this has worked for me. use the exact version as such python@3.9

First search available packages using

```
brew search python
```

Then install the version you want ex:

```
brew install python@3.9
```